# How do I split content from a command line

Tags: powershell, split

My question is how I split content prompted from a command line in powershell
I want to find all the OU's path on my server, so I can use them later on..

```
get-aduser -Filter * | Select DistinguishedName | findstr "OU="

OUTPUT
CN=Username1,OU=firma1,DC=bc,DC=local
CN=Username2,OU=firma2,DC=ad,DC=local

and I want only 
OU=firma1,DC=bc,DC=local
OU=firma2,DC=ad,DC=local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |
    Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName.IndexOf('OU=') -gt 0 } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.DistinguishedName.Substring($_.DistinguishedName.IndexOf('OU=')) }
```

This code filters out any objects that aren't in an OU, which includes those which are in the `Users` built-in container, like `CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=bc,DC=local`.  You could also handle those users with an `if` statement in the `ForEach-Object`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the .NET [`String.Split` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) directly

```
Get-ADUser -Properties DistinguishedName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.DistinguishedName.Split(",", 2)[1]
}
```

This splits the `DistinguishedName` into two parts at the comma (i.e. everything before the first comma and everything after) and returns the second part only (array index `[1]`).

I would probably add a `Sort-Object` and a `Select-Object -Unique` to the end of that.

Worth a read: [`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adorganizationalunit?view=win10-ps), maybe that is what you are actually are looking for?

---

This approach is similar, with the PowerShell-native `-split` operator:

```
$DNs = Get-ADUser -Properties DistinguishedName | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$DNs -split ',',2 | where { $_.StartsWith("OU=") }
```

Comment: I came here to mention `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`. As asked that would work out nicely without any other manipulation required